# Merging Dataframes based on values

Tags: r

Apologies if I lack enough info in the question, first time posting here

I have two data frames, one with 12,000(GPS) second with 196 (Details).

The GPS dataframe has repeated values for a "names" column.

The Details datafame has a "position" column and a name column with a different position value for each name.

I need the GPS df to have a column "position" which pulls from Details$position but repeats each time a name is shown

I tried to do this by creating a list of the names and then using a combination of setDT & setDF using a line of code given to me by someone trying something similar:

```
Weigh_in_check <- setDF(setDT(Weigh_in_check)[setDT(Weight_first), 
Weight_initial := Weight_first$Weight, on=c("Name")])
```

however I cannot change it around for it to work for me with as follows

```
Name_check <- setDF(setDT(Name_check)[setDT(GPSReview2), Position := 
PlayerDetails$Position, on=c("Player Name")])
```

New code following comment by Flo.P

```
GPSReview4[,"Position"] <- NA
GPSReview4$Position <- as.character(GPSReview4$Position)
GPSReview4$Position <- left_join(GPSReview4, PlayerDetails, by ="Position" )
```

Which gives following error

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Position, value = list(`Full session` = c("Yes",  : 
  replacement has 132235 rows, data has 26447

**EDIT:
These are the 2 dataframes
[GPS Review4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y25Wf.png)

[Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5FWq.png)

Comment: A classic join should work. `dplyr::left_join(GPS, Details, by = "position")`

Comment: Hi @Flo.P, thanks for your comment.  I gave that a try as follows                

    > 'GPSReview4[,"Position"] <- NA
    > GPSReview4$Position <- as.character(GPSReview4$Position)
     > GPSReview4$Position <- left_join(GPSReview4, PlayerDetails, by ="Position" )'                                                                 and got the following error -                                  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Position, value = list(`Full session` = c("Yes",  : 
  replacement has 132235 rows, data has 26447

Comment: Replace `GPSReview4$Position <- left_join(GPSReview4, PlayerDetails, by ="Position" ) `by `GPSReview4<- left_join(GPSReview4, PlayerDetails, by ="Position" ) `

Comment: When I made that change it replicated each row in GPSReview4 5 times without bringing the position info across also? Thanks

Comment: You can try this: `GPSReview4<- left_join(GPSReview4, PlayerDetails, by ="names" )`. BTW the data you have shared hasn't got any column with as `names`.

Comment: @MKR That worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilCollins Im happy it worked for you. I still cannot see data.frames as part of link. You can simply use `dput(head(GPSReview4, 5))` and share it with question.